# Django's admin 'change' view not accepting kwargs={'object_id':'blah}

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm a little thrown by this. I have the following code, which works perfectly well:

```
urlresolvers.reverse('admin:cards_card_change', args=([92]))
```

To further my understanding, I wanted to try rewriting the line as:

```
urlresolvers.reverse('admin:cards_card_change', kwargs={'object_id':92})
```

as seemingly suggested by [the documentation on reversing admin views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) (I'm using Django 1.4).

However, this doesn't seem to match anything at all. Why not? I tried looking in the django source code for answers, but couldn't find the view used for change, so links to the relevant module there would be really helpful as well!

Comment: While it is possible to define `urlpatterns` that support keyword arguments, this is not the case with the admin URLs. When reversing admin URLs, only positional (and not keyword) arguments are supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `urlpattern` of the change view is in [admin/options.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L386):

```
url(r'^(.+)/$',
    wrap(self.change_view),
    name='%s_%s_change' % info),
```

You could find that it dispatches a request to the `change_view` method of the `ModelAdmin` instance. The `change_view` method also resides in [admin/options.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1012):

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    ...
```

It does accept a parameter `object_id`.

The reason of the missing match of `reverse` is that the `urlpattern` above does not accept named parameter, if you change it to something like

```
url(r'^(?P<object_id>.+)/$',
    wrap(self.change_view),
    name='%s_%s_change' % info),
```

The `urlresolvers.reverse('admin:cards_card_change', kwargs={'object_id':92})` should work.

I've no idea whether it was intended to avoid some edge cases or it's just a bug and there's already a ticket fixing this. I'll check it later.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - a really helpful answer. A quick question just to make sure that I understand, and can get this right next time - was I right to assume that the documentation suggests the kwargs usage, or am I misinterpreting what it is saying?

Comment: @GregPallis `kwargs` usage works as well as as `args` usage, normally. Here `Admin`'s missing named group fails the `kwargs` usage. The document uses `args` usage currently, so keep w/ it until `kwargs` usage is available in reversing Admin URLs

Comment: @GregPallis seems its a bug. I've reported [a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19406#ticket) for this

Comment: It looks like the ticket @GregPallis reported stalled, with comments from Django maintainers to the effect that the admin URLs have always accepted only positional arguments. So, the answer to this question really seems to be: 'When reversing admin URLs, only positional (and not keyword) arguments are supported.'

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a python syntax issue.
The thing is that `**kwargs` cannot be taken as `*args`.
The function you're trying to call has a first argument (`object_id`) which is positional and cannot be used as a named argument. (Someone tell me if I'm wrong)

For you, `object_id` is a positional argument, and thus will be ignored if used in kwargs

If you want your view function to accept object_id also in kwargs, you have to change it with for example

```
my_id = kwargs.get('object_id', args[0])
```

Comment: When the view is called, `object_id` can be provided as a positional argument or a keyword argument. You don't need to change the view as you suggest. The problem, as @okm says in their answer, is that the change view does not use named groups in the regular expression.